# has_many association Rails4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

A rails newbie here,  I'm created has_many assocation for category and product but getting error when checking the relationship in console

```
2.2.0 :004 > Category.last.products
  Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 with ruby 2.2.0

Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Product Model

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :product_name
      t.float :price, precision: 5, scale: 2, default: 0.00
      t.boolean :is_available, default: true
      t.integer :category_id
      t.string :description
      t.integer :quantity

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that you have no records in `Category` model.

When you call `Category.last` you get nil object because you have no records, and when you call `products` it gets called on nil object.

First create record in database, with `Category.create` then you can call `Category.last` and it will give you last record, then when `products` gets called it will be called on last `category`, and won't give you undefined method for nil object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any Category object.

`Category.last.products`

> NoMethodError: undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass